# Time slot generation based on available technicians

Tags: algorithm

Consider an Organization which provides technicians for different types of jobs.

Each job type varies in completion time and technician count. For e.g., Job type 1 requires 2 technicians and 1 hour to complete and job type 2 requires 1 technician and 30 minutes to complete. All technicians are available all the time (Organization working time is 09:00-18:00) unless they are assigned any jobs.

A customer can request the service online and an available time slot should be displayed based on the selected job type.

There are no other constraints like minimum shift or maximum shift per technician, and also assume that all technicians are equally skilled.

What is the best possible way to generate the time slot?

Comment: You need to study `greedy algorithm task scheduling` and modify it with technician count constraint.

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you are describing is a variant of the [`Producer-Consumer Problem`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem), wherein you have jobs which are consumed by technicians.

Since, as you say, all the technicians have the same skill, you do not really need to find the *optimal* technician for the job at hand. Thus, to solve the problem all that you need is really a pool of technicians (you could look at this as a Thread Pool) and every time that a job comes, you assign one of your technicians to the job on a first come first serve basis.

Should there be no technicians available, then the job is queued until a technician is made available.

Comment: By creating a pool how can I assign multiple technicians for a single job?

Comment: @frosty: Part of the job description if you will, will have the amount of workers needed. You will then ask the pool the give you that amount of workers. If there aren't enough available you would still queue the job and then either have the pool fire an event each time new workers are available or else poll the worker pool every period of time to see if any new workers are available.